# Why I get foo result when my query is set to where not equal to foo in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

```
rows = Campaign::with('limitations');
$rows->whereHas('limitations', function($q){
       $q->where('country_id', '!=', Auth::user->countryId)->where('type', 'foo2');
});
```

Despite the line

```
$q->where('country_id', '!=', Auth::user->countryId)
```

I'm still getting rows that has 'foo' in it. I have tried using '<>' and '!=' but both doesn't work. What's the problem in my lines of code? Or is this a Laravel bug?

**UPDATE:**

If I change the code to this

```
$q->where('country_id', '!=', Auth::user->countryId)->where('type', '!=', 'foo2');
```

I will get results that are not 'foo2', but it doesn't work with the Auth::user->country_id.

**TABLE STRUCTURE:**

**Campaign**
id, has_limit

**User**
id, countryId

**Campaign_has_limitations**
id, campaign_id, country_id, type

Comment: `$q->where('column', '!=', 'foo')
 $q->where('column2', 'foo2');`?

Comment: @aldrin27 do you mean `$q->where('column', '!=', 'foo'); $q->where('column2', 'foo2');` ??

Comment: Yes try that. I think because your using `$q` inside your function

Comment: @aldrin27 tried it gives the same result as my codes in the question

Comment: What is the version of your laravel?

Comment: @aldrin27 laravel 4.2

Comment: Can i see the columns of your two tables?

Comment: Where's the table structure?

Comment: @aldrin27 i have added in and those are the columns that are related to my question

Comment: What is `Model` in your query?

Comment: I think you must join the table. What you are doing is Eloquent.

Comment: @aldrin27 I did declare their relationship in the Campaign model, `public function limitations(){
        return $this->hasMany('Campaign_Has_Limitations');
    }`

Comment: You could use `whereExist` clause. It might solve your problem.

Comment: You mean: `Auth::user()->countryId` with "**()**"? Also in the updated question you write a code sample with: `Auth::user->countryId`, but below, your text says `Auth::user->country_id`. **Suggest to check your tables properly**, because `Auth::user()->notExistingField` will be null, and won't give any error!

Comment: @Iamzozo yes i made sure all the columns are correct, error was not because of that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$countryid = Auth::user->countryId;
rows = Campaign::whereHas('limitations', function($q) use ($countryid) {
   $q->where('country_id', '!=', $countryid)
     ->where('type', '!=', 'foo2');
});
```

Comment: True. I edited it. You have to pass the variable with `use`